# Substitution in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I like to evaluate the following in linux shell

```
CMD_6='ls'
CMD_7='ls -l'
VER=6
CMD="CMD_"$VER
```

I'm expecting `$CMD` to execute CMD_6 and list the directory content, but it is throwing an error:

```
-bash: CMD_6: command not found
```

Can someone explain how to do this substitution?

Comment: `CMD_6` isn't a command; it's a variable name, and variable expansions aren't recursive.

Answer (score 6):

Use functions.

```
cmd_6 () { ls; }
cmd_7 () { ls -l; }
ver=6
cmd="cmd_$ver"
"$cmd"
```

The value of `cmd` shouldn't be any more complicated than a single function or command name: no arguments, no other shell syntax.

Answer (score 2):

... or use aliases:

```
$ alias cmd_6='ls'
$ ver=6
$ alias cmd="cmd_$ver"
$ alias
alias cmd='cmd_6'
alias cmd_6='ls'
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers explain how to to it with functions and aliases, but it *can* be done with variables:

```
foo="ls -l" bar=/bin/bash
$foo $bar
```

Output:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1099016 May 17  2017 /bin/bash
```

---

But this is a little different:

```
CMD="CMD_"$VER
```

To run it, do:

```
eval \$$CMD
```

Be careful with `eval`, only feed it known or checked input.